# How to find MX Records in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2010

Just finished building out an Exchange 2010 server to host our e-mail on-site.  Called GoDaddy to have the MX Records pointed to the External IP address of our Exchange server but was asked by GoDaddy what our MX Records were.

My question is:  Where in Exchange 2010 can I find what the MX Records are?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Why are you even _calling_ GoDaddy? If your DNS is hosted there, you can just login to the web site and change the records yourself.

Answer (score 2):

An MX record doesn't "point" to an ip address. An MX record designates the host that email should be delivered to. That host needs to have an A record, which in turn resolves to an ip address.

So if your MX record designates mail.newfrontiertech.com as the server that email should be delivered to for the newfrontiertech.com domain then you need to have GoDaddy create an A record for mail.newfrontiertech.com, then have them create an MX record that designates mail.newfrontiertech.com.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I think I get it now or at least know what to ask of GoDaddy.